# save sprated with comma in row in sql server and exclude some column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL table like this
Table:1

```
CERT SPEC  ClientID
all   1    8
all   2    8
all   3    8
1    all   9
2    all   9
```

Table: 2
certs

```
ID  Name
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

Table: 3
SPECS

```
ID  Name
1   X
2   Y
3   Z
```

Result table

```
CERT SPEC   ClientID
all   X,Y,Z 8
A,B   all   9
```

I have use **stuff** and **xml path for** but did not get the expected result.
Please help me with this.

Comment: Don't do this; never store delimited data in your DBMS. But there are already 100's of examples on how to achieve it in SQL Server on SO.

Comment: Don't do that - that breaks the most basic rule, 1st Normal Form - a cell holds one value. It's now extremely hard to find rows where `SPEC` contains `y` and almost impossible to add another relation

Comment: It looks like he want a `SELECT` statement, not really storing the data into table @Larnu

Comment: Result "Table" suggests to me a table, rather than a result/dataset @Sami . But regardless, the dupe tells them what to do if they really want to pursue a denormalised data set; both in more recent and older versions of SQL Server. At best, considering that they have a normalised design, it would be better if they use a `VIEW`, rather than "store" the data in a "result *table*".

Comment: @Sami the title clearly says 'store'

Comment: Fair enough Larnu. @P.Salmon I always try to learn the Q not just the title especially when the OP is a new user or maybe he has poor english.